# delegate ItemClick event handling to child's click event handling (scaleform)

Tags: actionscript-2

ItemClick event is of gfx.control.ScrollingList.
This ScrollingList MovieClip has two child buttons.

I'd like to handle these children's click event.

```
private function configUI() {
  super.configUI();
  // MyList : ScrollingList;
  MyList.addEventListener( "itemClick", this, "OnListItemClicked" );
}
private function OnListItemClicked( e : Object ) {
    // how???
    // e.renderer?
}
```

e.renderer is of type "MyListItemRenderer extends ListItemRenderer".

Answer (score 0):

if you're using CLIK AS3 the event should actually be of type 
scaleform.clik.events.ListEvent
It includes the 'itemData' for the clicked list item (the data you gave the list which corresponds to the entry the user clicked on) and 'index' the index that was clicked. Also, by default the list marks as 'selected' the item that was clicked, so you could just ask the list:

```
private function OnListItemClicked( e : ListEvent ) 
{
    var myDataObj:Object = e.itemData;

    var clickedIdx:int = e.index;
    // or
    clickedIdx = MyList.selectedIndex;
}
```

If you're using the AS2 CLIK I imagine it is similar, but I've not used that version so can't say for sure.